# How to pass a function to each mapped items from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, array-map

On a component, i mapped each item from an array that comes from an API, and am returning them on a `<li>` each, like this:

```
const usersComponent = usersData.map((user: any) => (
      <li
        key={user.Username}
        className="px-4 my-2 lg:pl-8 w-full scale-95 transform transition duration-500 hover:scale-100"
      >
      \\ rest of the code
```

Then, on the component, i do:

```
return (
  <ul>{usersComponent}</ul>
)
```

Now, each item on this list is a `username` in my API, and these usernames have groups on my database, but the groups only return in another GET from the API, which i have on this other function:

```
async function listGroupsForUser(username: string) {
    const apiName = 'AdminQueries'
    const path = '/listGroupsForUser'
    const myInit = {
      body: {
        username
      }, 
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `${(await Auth.currentSession())
          .getAccessToken()
          .getJwtToken()}`,
      },
    }
    return await API.get(apiName, path, myInit)
  }
```

So, i need to pass this `listGroupsForUser` for each of the `<li>` i mapped, then it will return an array for each one of them, and i need to map it, for each one, individually.

I tried in many ways but couldn`t do it.

Comment: You can make the individual item in the `map` to be its own React component, and then in that component you can make your `listGroupsForUser` request, and fill up the HTML accordingly.

Comment: could you elaborate further on that, please? If i understood correctly, i create a, lets say <User /> component in another file, with a props.username, then inside of it, i pass the function like so: `listGroupsForUser(username)`, is that correct?

Comment: Here's a simple example illustrating this concept: https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-resonance-jo48b?file=/src/UserList.tsx

Comment: If you have 50 users being displayed in the list, are you making 50 API calls for the groups?

Comment: @SamuelGoldenbaum yes, and it is a bummer, this API is f*cking sh*it, it is the rest api for the AdminQueries in AWS Amplify. If the `listUsers` GET request would return the group for the user, that would make my life much easier cause the group would return in the first array im mapping, but it doesn't. So i have to get each group from this `listGroupsForUser` GET request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends if you need to fetch all the data upfront, or if you can fetch the groups asynchronously.

To fetch them all ahead, you could use [Promise.All](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and fire off the queries in parallel like:

```
const getRandomDelay = (min: number, max: number): number => {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
};

// mock API call
const fetchGroups = (username: string): Promise<string[]> => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      return resolve(['admin', 'editor']);
    }, getRandomIntInclusive(2000, 4000));
  });
};

const data = ['darth', 'fett', 'luke'];

interface User {
  name: string;
  groups?: string[];
}

export default function App() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState<User[] | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    Promise.all(
      data.map(async (user) => {
        const groups = await fetchGroups(user);
        return {
          name: user,
          groups: groups
        };
      })
    ).then((result) => {
      setUsers(result);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {users &&
        users.map((user) => (
          <div key={user.name}>
            {user.name}&nbsp;
            {user.groups.map((group) => (
              <span key={group}>{group}, </span>
            ))}
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Alternately, you could use a hook within each. Something like:

```
const useListGroupsForUser = (username: string) => {
  const [groups, setGroups] = useState<string[] | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.info(`mocking fetch for ${username}`);
    fetchGroups(username).then((result) => setGroups(result));
  }, [username]);

  return {
    groups
  };
};

// User component
const User = ({ user }: UserProps) => {
  const { groups } = useListGroupsForUser(user);

  return (
    <li>
      {user} <br />
      {groups ? groups.map((group) => group) : <span>loading groups...</span>}
    </li>
  );
};

// and render in App
{data.map((user) => (
    <User key={user} user={user}/>
))}
```